# Время хранения кук без явного указания времени хранения.

Tags: php, cookie

Сколько будет хранится кука, установленная вот так:

```
SetCookie("Test","Value");
```

? Спасибо :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Эта "кука" будет хранится до тех пор пока пользователь не закроет браузер.
Это **имитация сессии**